# Are there any magical plants mainly used for food purposes?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter, J.K. Rowling unveils a series of plants, most of them used mainly for healing, or decoration. In the wizarding world, they eat a lot of common muggle  food, using muggle ingredients. Are there any wizarding plants mainly used as ingredients in food, that are specifically magical?(Excluding all of the sweets sold at various locations)

Comment: [Spellbinding nuts?](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Spellbinding_Nuts?file=SpellbindingNuts.jpg)

Comment: [Gurdyroot](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Gurdyroot) seems to fit the bill. It's certainly not mundane in origin and its main purpose seems to be to make a foul-tasting elixir of indeterminate usage

Comment: @Valorum what you serve when you don't want visitors

Answer (score 1):

## Probably.

I have stumbled across several plants that may or may not be magical but certainly aren't used in Muggle cuisine.

> Fruit preserve jars contain Crazyberry Jam, Forbidden Forest Blossom Honey, and Marmalade with Orange bits, made by the Hogwarts house-elves, with best-before dates (June in Pisces) on the label. [...] Goodness knows how the students kept their teeth after eating Pixie Puffs (made by Honeydukes), which contains sugar, glucose fructose syrup, African honey, glucose syrup, molasses, magical niacin, iron, fiber, riboflavin, choco, and pixie dust.
> <sub>*- Harry Potter, The Artifact Vault, Chapter 5 (Food and Drink)*</sub>

Some of the non-muggle plants in here are Crazyberries which do not exist in the Muggle world (unless you count the limited time flavor of Pop-Tart which was called Crazy Berry) but I can't be sure that they are strictly *magical* but this would seem the case otherwise why would they hide them from Muggles (this applies to the next plants as well). Forbidden Forest Blossom honey may be a different case though as it may just be a species of flower that grows in the forbidden forest and is thus too dangerous for Muggles to reach but there's still a chance it's magical.
[image]

Comment: Do you know if any of these are specifically used for food purposes? Some of them seem as though they may be, but no answers have been accepted because the plant is mainly used for other purposes, although it may be edible

Comment: @Ginge have you read my answer wrong? I provided the **food** then listed the ingredients some of which were possible magical plants.

Comment: I.e PixiePuffs and the Magical Niacin

Comment: I mean the plants... Crazyberries may be legit though...

Comment: they were all plant-based @Ginge

Comment: d'you know which plant magical Niacin comes from??

Comment: @Ginge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niacin

Comment: I've deleted that part

Comment: What would make it magical though?

Comment: the fact that it's called magical